# Using Lagrange Multipliers Better?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question, lagrange-multiplier

My question is that "Can we use lagrange multipliers to solve any problem where we need to find local/global minima/maxima?" Also, "Is it much easier to use lagrange multipliers, and if so what cases would it be better to do the conventional method of finding $f_x,f_y$ to find critical points, and then finding max/min?"

Comment: No method is universal, in that it has limitation of application and can produce subsidiary problems that are as difficult, or more so, than the original problem.  Since the Lagrange-multiplier method tests for points where the normal vector of a level "curve" or "surface" of the function to be extremized matches the direction of the normal vector of the constraint function, it generally is only telling us about what happens at boundaries of regions.  So you usually still need to check for critical points in the interior of the region as well.  (continued)

Comment: Also, if you check any number of posts with the "lagrange-multiplier" tag on this site, you'll find many situations where it can be very difficult to actually _solve_ the "Lagrange equations" for the points of interest.  To answer your second question ambivalently, sometimes "multipliers" make things much easier (occasionally, even "trivial"), and sometimes they leave you with little more information than you started with.

Answer (score 2):

The method of Lagrange's multipliers is a theorem with a few assumptions. Check it out on your favorite advanced calculus book. But, what is even more important, this method works for constrained critical points and should not be seen as an alternative to solving $\nabla f=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrange multipliers method is a procedure to find the maximum and minimum of functions of multiple variables subject to restrictions, so it is not a universal method since it works with some conditions or assumptions